# Nested condition in hibernate fails with Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have 3 entities

A,B and C

with one to one relation between A and B
many to one relation between B and C

When I access entity 'A', I am able to drill down and get the values of C

However when I have a nested condition in my HQL, I get null pointer exception

Query looks like

`from(A) where A.B.C.some_parameter.eq(value)`

I have added

`<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />`

in my configuration, but still I keep getting Null pointer exception

Comment: Mind posting a stack-trace excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not even remotely valid HQL :)

1) You do not wrap entity references in parenthesis; its just `from A`

2) You want to further dereference that A reference, so typically you would alias it like `from A a`

3) Assuming .eq is an attempt to perform equality comparison, its `where a.b.c.someProperty = value`

4) fetch_depth has absolutely no bearing here.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be..

```
"from A a where a.B.C.some_parameter = value"
```

check the reference, Hibernate **Lazy** must be false between A, B and C. The property you have defined I don't think that has any dependency on your desire. Also for the entity you executing the query must have complete bridge from A to C and C's property you are using in where clause.